# How to preload images on JS

Tags: image, preload

How to make preloader image like in the Tumblr. Example - http://micp.ru/kl4hb

Thanks.

Comment: [3 ways to preload images](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/)